# When I install RTools, RStudio stops working

Tags: r, installation, crash, rstudio, rtools

I have tried to install `RTools`, and RStudio stops working when it's installed. It freezes at launch: the loading never ends. I have the good version of RTools : I tried `RTools 3.5` for `R 3.6` and `RTools 4 for R 4.10`.

`RStudio` stop working when `RTools` is installed, regardless of the version. And when I uninstall `RTools` from Windows, RStudio works again.

When I installed `Rtools` for the first time for `R 4.0`, I executed this line ; as it is mentioned on the website. Since that, it crashes.

> `writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con =        "~/.Renviron")`

Any ideas?

I use RStudio 1.4.1717.
Here's the output of `sessionInfo()` :

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=French_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0
```

Thanks !

Joël

Comment: Can you post your `sessionInfo()` please, and what `version` of `RStudio` are you using?

Comment: Install the latest version of `R`, and `RStudio`, then delete your question if it solves the problem.

Comment: I have this problem since a long time, I have updated R and RStudio many times and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, please update it again. Also R Studio, then I can help you.

Comment: I have updated, RStudio still freezes. When I open it, a window opens (as it was looking for a file ??), and the R session never starts.

Comment: Ok good - and `RStudio` is also updated? What version of `RStudio` are you using?

Comment: I've also updated RStudio, I've installed the last version : 1.4.1717.

Comment: Since I have updated R & RStudio, impossible to reinstall some packages... Tidyverse is not working anymore, for example, and refuses to reinstall... I think R is broken on my system, and reinstall it doesn't solve anything. It makes me crazy, I don't understand.

Comment: If it happens regardless of the version, it might be a config file hanging around across installs.  Can you check the contents of the various R config files for anything weird (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf)?

Comment: It was the .Renvironment file. I have deleted it, and that works again. Thank you !