# Weird problem when I try to install some packages on R

Tags: r, installation, package, rstudio

I have updated R & RStudio, now I have `R 4.1.0` with `RStudio 1.4.1717`.

Since the reinstallation, I cannot reinstall some packages like `tidyverse`.

Here's the message :

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installation du package dans ‘C:/Users/Gloubi/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(car ‘lib’ n'est pas spécifié)
installation des dépendances ‘broom’, ‘rvest’


  Des versions binaires sont disponibles mais les versions des sources sont plus récentes:
      binary source needs_compilation
broom  0.7.8  0.7.9             FALSE
rvest  1.0.0  1.0.1             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/tidyverse_1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 430032 bytes (419 KB)
downloaded 419 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Gloubi\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi4eTEj\downloaded_packages
installation des packages sources ‘broom’, ‘rvest’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 631606 bytes (616 KB)
downloaded 616 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rvest_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 94307 bytes (92 KB)
downloaded 92 KB

Impossible de configurer l'écran au nombre de lignes et de colonnes spécifié.
Impossible de configurer l'écran au nombre de lignes et de colonnes spécifié.

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Gloubi\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi4eTEj\downloaded_packages’
```

That are the `boom` and `rvest` dependencies that are the problem. The error is (my system is in french) : "Unable to configure the screen to the specified number of rows and columns." What does this mean ? This error doesn't seem common.

So, when I want to load `tidyverse`, it says :

```
Error: le chargement du package ou de l'espace de noms a échoué pour ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
aucun package nommé ‘broom’ n'est trouvé
```

If you tell me to install RTools, I have an other problem : [When I install RTools, RStudio stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68549944/when-i-install-rtools-rstudio-stops-working)
In any case, `tidyverse` does not require compilation, isn't it ?

I only have this problem at home, not at work, so it seems something is broken with R or RStudio on my system ??

Comment: Have you installed Rtools?

Comment: That's certainly a part of the problem : I can't install RTools (see the end of my post)

Comment: Weird question, but can you run "cmd" (Windows key + R -> cmd) successfully? This thread (https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/7jjey0/cmd_shows_the_screen_cannot_be_set_to_the_number/), which I certainly can't vouch for, implies it's possible "cmd" is being hijacked.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1286090/the-screen-cannot-be-set-to-the-number-of-lines-and-columns-specified .  That contains the exact English version of your error message, which might make it easier to google

Comment: Indeed, cmd doesn't run, it closes directly. So it would be a virus ?

Comment: Could be.  I'd take a look at the superuser suggestions - running Malwarebytes as a starting point.

Comment: update all your packages!

Comment: I can't update all the packages. I have all the latest binaries but I can't compile from sources, because as I said RTools doesn't work. Apart from that, Malwarebytes didn't find any virus. Maybe I will format my computer because all those erros don't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I succeeded to install RTools, and it is still impossible to install some packages, like `broom` and `rvest` (dependencies of `tidyverse`).

Here's the error, it is still very weird :

```
> install.packages(c("broom", "rvest"))
Installation des packages dans ‘C:/Users/Gloubi/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(car ‘lib’ n'est pas spécifié)

  Des versions binaires sont disponibles mais les versions des sources sont plus récentes:
      binary source needs_compilation
broom  0.7.8  0.7.9             FALSE
rvest  1.0.0  1.0.1             FALSE

installation des packages sources ‘broom’, ‘rvest’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 631606 bytes (616 KB)
downloaded 616 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rvest_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 94307 bytes (92 KB)
downloaded 92 KB

Impossible de configurer l'écran au nombre de lignes et de colonnes spécifié.
find: '/I': No such file or directory
find: '/N': No such file or directory
find: 'FirewallModule.exe': No such file or directory
find: '/I': No such file or directory
find: '/N': No such file or directory
find: 'explorer.exe': No such file or directory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
Impossible de configurer l'écran au nombre de lignes et de colonnes spécifié.
find: '/I': No such file or directory
find: '/N': No such file or directory
find: 'FirewallModule.exe': No such file or directory
find: '/I': No such file or directory
find: '/N': No such file or directory
find: 'explorer.exe': No such file or directory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I'm absolutely convinced the problem comes from windows not being able to run cmd.  R is trying to run it as part of the install, and failing.  A bit of googling shows FirewallModule.exe is a crypto currency miner, so not something that'd normally be run in an R package install.  This reddit page might help: https://www.reddit.com/r/antivirus/comments/fzjqb2/help_w_removing_crypto_virus/ - you'll have to update some registry settings as well as deleting the executable. Or there's this on the Malwarebytes forum: https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/268439-cmd-problem-slow-loading/

Comment: You're my saver, that was that ! I have followed the procedure in reddit, and cmd works again. So Rtools too. Thanks !

Comment: Excellent news - very glad to hear it! Still a little surprised Malwarebytes didn't pick it up, but glad your problem is solved